# What are the mechanics of DeFi Yield Farms?

Tags: defi, polygon

TL;DR: Does anyone have any literature or other resources they can point me at for how DeFi works under the hood, like really. How/why do percentages change, and where are defi operators pulling rewards from?

Apologies for long thread, trying to understand DeFi:

So I've been doing (high risk, huge(5Billion% APY) percentage) yield farming on Matic for the last week or so and been making absolute bank. Anyone here know how the mechanics of this work? I'm deliberately NOT providing any specific tokens or links in this thread as I don't really want to advertize on a learning site, but I'm happy to share in the comments if it's helpful.

Like I understand how LP provision works on the various AMMs (they use the lp to allow trade between coinA and coinB allowing trades (in principle) between pretty much arbitrary pairs. To incentivize people to provide liquidity, people get lp tokens which allocate a portion of every transaction in the given pair, proportional to the number of lp tokens held to the holder, paid in additional lp tokens)

Great, so far so good.

So I'm staking a CoinA-CoinB pair at @!#%@f134% percent APR through a super shit tier defi provider.

1. What's in it for the Defi operator? I'm in no way propping up their boutique in house shitcoin....
2. Why/how is this even possible? How are they paying me my absurd rewards? Again, denominated in the underlying LP token, *not* their boutique in house shitcoin?
3. What's in it for the operator (let's assume their not a rug for a moment)? It's not in their boutique shitcoin so it's not propping up value on an asset they control and nobody does things for free ... so...

I'd really love if someone could take the time to walk me through this, or, at least, recommend some resources.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the contract, there isn't a single way to create a farming token. Do you have the contract source?

Comment: So the farming token is "FISH": https://polygonscan.com/address/0x3a3df212b7aa91aa0402b9035b098891d276572b#code

But what I'm really interested in here isn't so much the tokenomics of FISH, as the mechanics of the NON FISH denominated LP pools so stuff in here:

https://polycat.finance/vaults